# Nested JSON to sql server tables

Tags: json, sql-server-2012

I have a nested JSON file. I need to insert the data in sql server tables.

```
{

    "2": {
        "Nome": {
            "EN": "Test EN ",
            "RU": "Test RU"
        },
        "Id": "2",
        "Items": {
            "100": {
                "Country": {
                    "EN": "World",
                    "RU": "Мир"
                },
                "SubN": {
                    "EN": "Test SUBN EN",
                    "RU": "Test SUBN RU"

                },
                "Id": "100",
                "Items": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "3": {
        "Nome": {
            "EN": "Test EN",
            "RU": "Test RU"

        },
        "Id": "4",
        "Items": {
            "200": {
                "Country": {
                    "EN": "Austria",
                    "RU": "Австрия"

                },
                "SubN": {
                    "EN": "Test SUBN EN",
                    "RU": "Test SUBN RU"

                },
                "Id": "200",
                "Items": {
                    "1000": {
                        "E1": {
                            "EN": "Test E1 En",
                            "RU": "Test E1 Ru"

                        },
                        "E2": {
                            "EN": "Test E1 En",
                            "RU": "Test E1 Ru"

                        },
                        "Id": "1000",
                        "Items": null
                    },
                    "1001": {
                        "E1": {
                            "EN": "Test E1 En",
                            "RU": "Test E1 Ru"

                        },
                        "E2": {
                            "EN": "Test E1 En",
                            "RU": "Test E1 Ru"

                        },
                        "Id": "1001",
                        "Items": null
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried this, but I get this error:

> "The table (Items) cannot be the child table to itself in nested relations."

```
XmlDocument xml = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(System.IO.File.ReadAllText(test.txt"), "RootObject");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("Json Data");
        XmlReader xr = new XmlNodeReader(xml);
        ds.ReadXml(xr);


        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("conn");
        conn.Open();
        foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Bulk Insert Started table:" + dt.TableName);
            SqlBulkCopy bulk = new SqlBulkCopy(conn);
            bulk.DestinationTableName = "[" + dt.TableName.Replace('{', ' ').Replace('}', ' ') + "]";
            bulk.WriteToServer(dt);

        }
```

Comment: What is the language of your choice for pushing the data into sql-server-2012? Or is it a tool like the import/export wizzard of that product? Please add this detail and maybe what you already tried. A table schema of the receiving database table might also be helpful.

Comment: C#, or importing from sql server directly